# how to return a django view from within a celery task?

Tags: django, django-celery, celery-task

I need to return a form from inside a django celery task. My task is called from the following django view:

```py
class MyView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyForm
    success_url = '/create/form'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        # I call my task in here
        period.delay()
        print("Loading task...")

        return super(MyView, self).form_valid(form)
```

The name of my task is *"period"* and It compares dates with the objective to open a event while the condition in my *IF* is true. My *"event"* is a formulary that user has to confirm presence.

My task:

```py
from .views import MyAnotherView 
# others imports...

"""
    in my settings.py, I had to call tha task every minute:
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-periodic-events': {
        'task': 'myapp.tasks.period',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*'),
        }
    }
"""

@shared_task(serializer='json')
def period():
    event = MyModel.objects.get(id=1) # I limited my model to receive only one object

    request = RequestFactory.get('/another/form') 
    view = MyAnotherView() 

    week_d = week_day(event.day) # day is a field of my model
    event_d = event_day(week_d, event.hour) # hour is a field of my model
    conf_d = presence_confirm(event.before_days, event.begin_hour, event_d) # before_days and begin_hour are fields of my model

    utc_now = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcnow())
    n = utc_now.astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/Recife'))
    t_str = '{}-{}-{}'.format(n.year, n.month, n.day)
    t_hour = ' {}:{}'.format(n.hour, n.minute)

    today = t_str + t_hour
    today = datetime.strptime(today, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

    if (today >= conf_d) and (today < event_d):
        # HOW TO CALL MY FORMULARY???
        print("Call my formulary")
        view.setup(request)

    else:
        # another thing
```

The formulary that I want to show after call my task and while the condition is true It will come of the django Model following:

```py
class MyAnotherModel(models.Model):
    OPTIONS = (
        (True, 'Sim'),
        (False, 'Não'),
    )

    player = models.OneToOneField(MyUserModel, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    confirm = models.BooleanField(choices=OPTIONS, default=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

In short, I want my formulary appears while my condition is true. So for, I had try using, into my task, RequestFactory.get to catch the URL and call the view (MyAnotherView).

```py
     # ...
     request = RequestFactory.get('/another/form') 
     view = MyAnotherView() # View responsável em instanciar MyAnotherModel 
     # ...
     if (today >= conf_d) and (today < event_d):
        view.setup(request)
```

However, I had receive *ImportError: cannot import name 'MyAnotherView'*. If anyone can help me, I aprecciate!

Comment: Well, your error is quite clear, it just says that you don't have `MyAnotherView` defined in .views. You'd have to show us the folder structure to see why it cannot be imported. But my main question is about what you're trying to do here. Your celery task isn't running _within a request cycle_ since it's asynchronous. So "showing a view" is not possible. Showing to whom? The user's original request has already received a response from `MyView`, so the browser isn't waiting for anything.

Comment: @dirkgroten, Believe me, my structure is correct. It's a bit confusing indeed. Sorry about this! What I want is to enable a form for a certain period of time so that my users can fill it out. I have the time of an event and when users can confirm attendance. It is at this interval (between confirming attendance and the day of the event) that I would like to enable my form. If there is another way you can show me, I appreciate it.

Comment: what do you mean by "my formulary appears" (what's a formulary anyway)? Appears where? If you want to check whether a form should be shown or not, why do you need an asynchronous task for that? Your question and explanation make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: I want a form to be able to fill in the time frame I mentioned. To check if today matches the user-provided time range, I used celery, as seen above. From now on, I want to enable/show/ to the user when they click on the link, something like that. I don't know if this is the best way. Sorry for not being clear. I have no knowledge in celery to ask the "ideal" question, sorry about this, but I am striving to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was checking if today's date is between two dates. If so, I must "show" a form. This check I did with celery. And my question here was how I could do as long as today's date was between the dates to enable the form. 
I solved the problem as follows:

- My celery task is not running within a request cycle since it's asynchronous - @dirkgroten - I soon thought of creating a new field in my django model (MyModel):

```py
enable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

- Update this field within my task:

```py
    # ...
    if (today >= conf_d) and (today < event_d):
        event.enable = True
        event.save()

    else:
        event.enable = False
        event.save()
```

- Return this information as context within my template from my form view

```py
    # In MyAnotherView
    model = MyAnotherModel
    fields = ['player', 'confirm']
    success_url = '/list/users'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
        context['enable'] = obj.enable
        return context
```

```html
<!--This is the template that shows form-->
{% if enable %}
    {{ form }}
{% else %}
    <h2> Don't show <h2>
{% endif %}
```

If anyone thinks there is a better way, they can suggest me, but I will have that answer for now.